# Angular 2 Dynamic Template Directives does not work

Tags: javascript, angular, templates, ionic2

I have a component which takes in a dynamic template which looks like this:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let entity of entityList" #item>
    <ion-item (click)="navigateToDetail(entity.id)">
      <template [ngTemplateOutlet]="template" [ngOutletContext]="{entity: entity}"></template>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item-options side="right">
      <button ion-button color="danger"  *ngIf="config && config.canDelete" (click)="delete(entity.id)">
        <ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon>Delete
      </button>
      <button ion-button color="dark" >
        <ion-icon name="more"></ion-icon>More
      </button>
    </ion-item-options>
  </ion-item-sliding>
  <ion-list-header>
    <button *ngIf="config && config.canCreate" (click)="create()"
            ion-button full color="secondary">
      Create New<ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
    </button>
  </ion-list-header>
</ion-list>
```

and the typescript looks like so:

```
export class PageListBaseComponent<T extends IHasId> {

    @Input() template: TemplateRef<any>;
    @Input() detailPageType: any;
    @Input() config: PageListConfiguration
    @Input() set baseProvider(provider: ProviderBase<T>) {
        provider.getList().subscribe(entities =>  {
            this.entityList = entities;
            console.log(entities);
        });
    }

    public entityList: T[];

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
        console.log("ctor");
    }

    create() {
        if (this.config && this.config.canCreate) {
            //TODO: initialize entity
            let entity = {}
            this.navCtrl.push(this.detailPageType, { entity });
        }
    }

    delete(id: number) {
        console.log(id);

        if(this.config && this.config.canDelete)
        {
            this.baseProvider.deleteById(id).subscribe(result => {
                console.log(result);
            });
        }
    }

    navigateToDetail(id: number) {
        this.navCtrl.push(this.detailPageType, { id })
    }
}
```

And then I have a template that looks like so:

```
<template #myTemplate let-entity="entity">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-avatar item-left>
      <img src="http://modexenergy.com/wp-content/themes/modex_wp/img/avatar.png">
    </ion-avatar>
    <h2>{{ entity.email }}</h2>
    <ion-icon name="arrow-forward" item-right></ion-icon>
  </ion-item>
</template>
```

My issue is the `<ion-item>`  Right now I need to use it twice which I do not want to do,  For some reason if i try and render the items dynamically they do not appear in the list, so I need to leave `<ion-item>` wrapping the template, that would be fine, except the directives don't respect there parent.  Meaning if I use the `item-left` directive in a template, and the template does not include an `<ion-item>` my directives are ignored.

What can I do to fix this,  if I can get away with out using both that would be nice, but if not is there a way render the first `<ion-item>` with no style?

Comment: `ion-item` is so hard to custom. So don't use `template` tag inside `ion-item`. I ussualy write my item myself. If you still want to use `ion-item`, just write all you element inside and use `item-left` `item-right` to position content

Comment: @Duannx what do you mean you write the item yourself as in HTML and CSS

Comment: I mean i dont use `ion-item`. I just use `div` and style for this.

Comment: Okay thanks. I guess I'll have to end up doing that

Comment: @Duannx btw quality avatar man